# Execute code after a 10 minute delay in PHP

Tags: php, cron

I need to delay the execution of some code in PHP (for example; sending an email) by 10 minutes after an event (form submission).

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Would be my only option be to run a Cronjob every minute? Is this practical on shared hosting?

Comment: cron will be better there is no point of hang the script for 10 mins

Comment: Okay can you confirm some things here , Do you want a delay with in the cronJob , I mean , code in the cronjob has to be delayed ?

Comment: A cron job would certainly be a reasonable way of doing it.  It'd be practical if your hosting provides cron!  Do you need the delay to be exactly n mins? That'd be slightly trickier with cron.  If it's just at least n mins you'd be fine.

Comment: It seems like your only options are a LOOONG-running script (which your hosting probably won't allow) or queuing tasks and executing them periodically with cron.

Comment: Caling the Quartz library from PHP might be an option.  I don't know much about it (besides the fact that it is a Java library), if it is truly available to call in PHP, or if it uses cron under the covers.

Comment: Quartz looks very cool... Probably overkill for my project but.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using cronjobs is the best way.

If you can't use a cronjob on your shared hosting (ask the customer support), you can run a cronjob on a machine connected to the internet (i.e. your home computer) that runs a wget to a php page on your server, authenticate on it and then run the php code to send your email.

For the PHP code part I'll use a database table with all the emails to be sent, a creation_date field and a status field.

Your PHP code called by the job will simply do (in pseudo code):

```
$batchRecords = takeAbunchOfRecordsWhereStatus(NOT_SENT);
while($batchRecords) {
    if($creationDate + 10 minutes >= now()) {
        sendEmail();
        markRecordAsSent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Running the cronjob on another computer is a cool idea, thanks!

Comment: Search for "web cron job" and you'll find lots of sites offering remote 'cron' services.